# StringBuilder OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, exception, out-of-memory, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder that appends all the pixel in an image, this amount being extremely large. Every time I run my program, everything goes well, but once I change a pixel color (ArGB) I get a `OutOfMemoryException` at the spot where I clear the StringBuilder. **The problem is that I need to create an instance of `StreamWriter` then add my text to it THEN set the file path.|** My current code it:

```
StringBuilder PixelFile = new StringBuilder("", 5000);
Private void Render() 
{
//One second run, I get an OutOfMemoryException
PixelFile.Clear();
//This is in a for but cut it out for reverence. 
PixelFile.Append(ArGBFormat);
}
```

I do not know what is causing this. I have tried `PixelFile.Length = 0;` and `PixelFile.Capacity = 0;`

Comment: Why are you even using a `StringBuilder` for this?!

Comment: @Crono I am doing this because i want to save it to a text file, later on.

Comment: I think Streams are going to be your friend here.

Comment: @Locke: I think that a byte array is going to be a much better friend.

Comment: This seems like it might qualify as an XY problem (http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY+Problem). Why do you want to save a ***binary*** image to a ***text***-file in the first place?

Comment: Why not get the file name first, *then* write directly to the file? Seems kind of strange that you're going to generate everything before asking for the file where it needs to be saved.

Answer (score 6):

OutOfMemory probably means you're building the string too big for StringBuilder, which is designed to handle a very different type of operation.

While I'm at a loss for how to make StringBuilder work, let me point you at a more intuitive implementation that will be less likely to fail.

You can read and write from a file using direct binary through the [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) classes. This can also save you a lot of effort since you can make sure you're serializing bytes instead of character strings or entire words.

If you absolutely must use plaintext, consider the [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamreader) and [StreamWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.io.streamwriter) classes directly, as they won't throw exceptions for size. Remember, streams are intended for this sort of operation, StringBuilder is not, so Streams are far more likely to work with far less effort on your part.

EDIT:

> [When the maximum capacity is reached, no further memory can be allocated for the StringBuilder object, and trying to add characters or expand it beyond its maximum capacity throws either an ArgumentOutOfRangeException or an OutOfMemoryException exception.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx)

Therefore, this is a limitation of the StringBuilder class and cannot be overcome with your current implementation.

EDIT: Additional implementation

In addition to StreamWriters which can write directly to files, you can also use the [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx) class to pipe information to memory instead of disk. Be aware this could lead to slow performance of the program, and I recommend instead trying to refactor the process to only need to perform a stream once.

That being said, it is still possible.

```
var mem = new MemoryStream();
var memWriter = new StreamWriter(mem);
// TODO: use memWriter.Write as per StreamWriter
mem.Position = 0;    // This ensures you are copying your stream from the beginning

// TODO: Show your file save dialog
var fileStream = new StreamWriter(fileNameFromDialog);
mem.CopyTo(fileWriter);    // Perform the copy
```

Comment: How would I go about setting the `StreamWriter` path after I've declared it. I want to create an instance, write string, then get the path via `SaveFileDialog`.

Comment: You can't the StreamWriter's path after the stream is opened, since the stream opens based on directly piping memory to where you tell it to go.

However, if you want to put the stream into memory, then transfer it to a file, you can use a MemoryStream. I will update my answer to provide for this implementation